# How can I show a hidden div below each row using bootstrap table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

In my admin panel I've a user page where all users are showing using Bootstrap Table with sorting option, pagination option.

Now I want to show more information about a user below each row when I click on a **whole row** then a div box will appear with more information.

How can i show this hidden div box below the each row ?

**Javascript I'm using in html head section:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="media/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable();

    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var name = $('td', this).eq(0).text();

    } );
} );
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**Php & Html code I'm using in the html body section**

```
<?php
$getUser = mysql_query("select * from members ORDER BY user_id DESC");
$num = mysql_num_rows($getUser);
?>

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Position</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Kit type</th>                          
</tr>                          
</thead>                
<tbody>

<?php
$i = 0;
while($search_result =  mysql_fetch_array($getUser)){

    $i++;
    $uid = (int) $search_result['user_id']; 
    $email =  $search_result['email'];      
    $fname =  $search_result['fname'];  
    $lname  = $search_result['lname'];                  
    $company  = $search_result['company'];                  
    $position  = $search_result['position'];                    
    $status  = $search_result['status'];                        

    echo "<tr>";                                    
    echo "<td class='row' $class valign='top'>$fname</td>";
    echo "<td class='row' $class  valign='top'>$lname</td>";                
    echo "<td class='row' $class  valign='top'>$company</td>";
    echo "<td class='row' $class  valign='top'>$position</td>";
    echo "<td class='row' $class  valign='top'>$status</td>";
    echo "<td class='row' $class  valign='top'>$kittype</td>";      
    echo "</tr>";   
}
?>

    </tbody>    
</table>
```

Comment: Here's an example that my help: http://bootply.com/GGAMvot45f

Comment: @Baghoo Thanks for your link. Seems will work for me but how can I find the javascript code here ? I can only see html code.

Comment: It's using JS built into Bootstrap via the `collapse` plugin and data-attributes (ie; data-target=".row1") More here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

Comment: @Baghoo I can't see any sorting and pagination option on the link(first). In my my code it's showing pagination and sorting option. So is there any way to add a show/hide code ?